# Google form spreadsheet update script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I have some code for my form that works well for emailing the manager of an expense report for approval, as well as receiving a URL back with information needed to send the response back to the person who filled out the information on the form.

all i need it to do now is to update the field in the form with the proper approval message (accept or reject)

I think this will have to happen in the doGet method, but will I have to pass in more then just the row number and approval message to get this done? (e.g. getting the spreadsheet, getting the sheet, etc.)

here is what i have so far, both emails, and the URL generated appear to be correct:

```
function sendEmail(e){
  /**
 var email = e.values[1];
 var item = e.values[2]; 
 var cost = e.values[3];
  */
  var serviceInformation = e.values[1];
  var language = e.values[2];
  var meetingType = e.values[3];
  var eventDate = e.values[4];
  var clientName = e.values[5];
  var detailedDirections = e.values[6];
  var onSitePOCName = e.values[7];
  var onSitePOCNumber = e.values[8];
  var department = e.values[9];
  var contactPhoneNumber = e.values[10];
  var approval = e.values[11];  //the one we need to modify
  var requestorEmail = e.values[12];
  var managerEmail = e.values[13];
  var Language2 = e.values[14];
  var interpreterName = e.values[15];
  var interpreterAgency = e.values[16];
  var dateConformationSent = e.values[17];
  var specialNotes = e.values[18];
  var row = e.range.getRow();


  var url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/richmond.k12.va.us/s/AKfycbwuRr1boKTH0v1mprWmc7PE66_mQ_dmPE0lyWb7vkfiyW3pn31b/exec';


//add on the parameters to URL to send to the manager
  var approve = url + '?approval=true'+'&reply='+requestorEmail+'&row='+row;
  var reject = url + '?approval=false'+'&reply='+requestorEmail+'&row='+row;

      var html = "<HTML><body>"+
               "<h2>please review</h2><br />"
  +"<P>" + language +"  " + serviceInformation
  +"<p>" + meetingType+ "  on   "+ eventDate + "    for " +clientName
  +"<p>" + "Location: "+ department
  +"<p>" + "requester: "+ requestorEmail+ "  "+
    "<p>"+

    "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
      "<p>"+

    "<a href=" +reject+">Reject</a><br />"+
              "</HTML></body>";


MailApp.sendEmail(managerEmail, "Approval Request", "what no html?",   {htmlBody: html});

}


function doGet(e){
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params);


//added in an edit
var id = '1UzlJ6Uw12H5dGVcLz7ONp3Neehq1DL21hqZnrMx7mxs';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var column = 12; 
   var row = e.parameter.row;
   var approval_cell = sheet.getRange(row, column);
  Logger.log(row);
  Logger.log(ss);
  Logger.log(sheet);
  Logger.log(approval_cell);
 //logger logs the proper row.  SS = Spreadsheet,  sheet = sheet,  approval_cell = Range


  var aprovalResponce = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Approved.' :  'Sorry, you need to reschedule';

//added values after aprovalResponce, in the email, they are both undefined.
  var msg = "Your manager said : " + aprovalResponce;
  var replyEmail = e.parameter.reply;

   //MailApp.sendEmail(replyEmail, "Approval Request", msg);

   //update the approval field

  //changed in edit
   if (e.parameter.approval == 'true') {
    approval_cell.setValue("APPROVED"+;
  } else {
    approval_cell.setValue("DENIED");
  }


  //send the actual email out
  MailApp.sendEmail(replyEmail, "Approval Request", msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to change the approval value in the spreadsheet?  If so, I imagine this should work:

```
//update the approval field
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var column = 12; 
var row = e.parameter.row;
var approval_cell = sheet.getRange(row, column);

if (e.parameter.approval == 'true') {
    approval_cell.setValue("APPROVED");
} else {
    approval_cell.setValue("DECLINED");
}
```

Comment: this looks pretty similar to what i saw on this elsewhere, so it should probably work.  however, my code does not seem to be accepting any changes right now.  even after saving, and re publishing.  even tried something simple like adding to the email message text, and it still uses the old message

Comment: seems like the SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); is returning null when I use the DEV link for the code.  this is a bound script so I should have access to the file, but I think i need to look it up by ID.  but now it seems like docs is having service issues and I can not open up the spreadsheet right now to test.

wonder if this is why re-publising the code seems to do nothing for the text changes, as if it were still using an older version from days ago

Comment: ok, now that Google docs is back up, I got everything working (updated code above) and it pulls back a spreadsheet, sheet, and range as expected for the values above (from logger.log).  however, it still does not update the Approval column.

no other errors are thrown.  i did have to get the spreadsheet by ID instead of just the active one (as it was returning null) however, I dont think that should make much of a difference, since all the other method calls should be the same

Comment: great news, came in to work today and it was working with just a few changes, somehow it was adding the text to the right cell on a new sheet this morning that I did not tell it to make, once i grabbed the right sheet (var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];) it worked flawlessly.  I must have missed some global setting somewhere in the initial set up.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you reverse engineer some existing code and make it work for you.